# AddValueEventListener run if as well as else statement in firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am using addvalueEventListener function to fetch data from firebase. I am trying to achieve AND operation by using this function. Issue is that when I am calling this function, it can filter data client side and also show in recyclerview but it can run if statement if data found and also run else part.

Suppose I want data which is available in firebase, it filters the data and show and also run else part data not found.

My main function code is:

```
private void GetFilterData(final String filter) {

    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Donation");


    Query query = reference.limitToLast(20).orderByChild("username").equalTo(username);

    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

//Here I can check if data is exist or not, if exist it shows data
            if (dataSnapshot.exists())
            {
                arrayList.clear();
                alert.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    DonationHelper donationHelper = dataSnapshot1.getValue(DonationHelper.class);

//here I want to check again and filter data, if data exist, shows data and if does not exist required filter then run else part. But issue is that if data exist it shows data and also run its else part.
                    if (donationHelper.getAction().equals(filter))
                    {
                        pd.cancel();
                        arrayList.add(donationHelper);
                    }
                    else
                    {

//Filter data exist or not, everytime it run else part code
                        pd.cancel();
                        alert.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        alert.setText("Currently no request is in Queue");
                        //Toast.makeText(Track_Donation.this, "No data found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    adapter = new DonationAdapter(Track_Donation.this,arrayList);
                    donationdata.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                pd.cancel();
                alert.setText("Start do Donation, and help Poor and Needy people's");
                Toasty.error(Track_Donation.this, "You don't do any Donation yet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            pd.cancel();
            Toasty.error(Track_Donation.this, "Server Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what the problem is. Can you edit your question to say which line of your code doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have added comments on code...kindly check

Comment: Are you sure that you are pointing to the right reference? Check if you are setting the right paths. Remember that the names of the children are case-sensitive, that means if you call a child "users" you can't call it from code with "Users".

Comment: Yes I'm damn sure, because all data retrieval is smooth and fine. Just one issue is that it shows data as well as show toast data not found.